# At which Step of normalization i should include the new Primary Key Column

Tags: database, normalization

I have a table with the following data.
I need to Normalize them as per Normalization Rules, but I am confused, on which step of normalization I should introduce CustomerId as new PrimaryKey column.

```
 CustomerName Address    ObjectRented    objectCatetory
-------------------------------------------------------
Mr A         Street 1    Obj1,Obj2       Cat1,Cat1
Mr B         Street 2    Obj3,Obj4       Cat2,Cat2
MR B         Street 3    Obj2            Cat1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example, you can introduce primary key column even before doing normalization. Your table could just look denormalized like this after adding primary key (simplified structure):

```
CustomerID CustomerName  Address  ObjectRented
---------- ------------- -------  ------------
1          Mr A          Street 1 Obj1,Obj2
2          Mr B          Street 2 Obj3,Obj4
2          Mr B          Street 3 Obj2
```

I am writing this rather quickly, so please do read up on other answers and blogs about normal forms as well.

**1NF - Remove repeating group**

```
CustomerID CustomerName  Address  ObjectRented
---------- ------------- -------  ------------
1          Mr A          Street 1 Obj1
1          Mr A          Street 1 Obj2
2          Mr B          Street 2 Obj3
2          Mr B          Street 2 Obj4
2          Mr B          Street 3 Obj2
```

**2NF - Remove partial dependency**

CustomerID is actually a customer and lives at a particular location. Keep them in a single table. Customer can rent whatever they like...keep whatever they rented in a different table like this:

Customers

```
CustomerID CustomerName  Address
---------- ------------- -------
1          Mr A          Street 1
2          Mr B          Street 2
2          Mr B          Street 3
```

ObjectRental

```
CustomerID ObjectRented
---------- ------------
1          Obj1
1          Obj2
2          Obj3
2          Obj4
2          Obj2
```

During this stage, you can also move Objects into its own table

Objects

```
ObjectID ObjectName
-------- ----------
1        Obj1
2        Obj2
3        Obj3
4        Obj4
```

ObjectRental becomes

```
CustomerID ObjectRentedID
---------- ------------
1          1
1          2
2          3
2          4
2          2
```

At this point I believe you have automatically gained 3NF. In 3NF, you'd want to make sure that - loosely speaking - none of your child table's primary key associates with a non-primary key in parent table.

Comment: So is it okay to add CustomerID before moving to 1NF, because i have to prove it that it should be there before 1NF, i have  read about composite keys do you think if i go with customerName and address as composite key ?

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely okay to add CustomerID before even starting normalization process. Also, do not create a composite key on customer name and address. CustomerName can change  and customerAddress can change. Use keys that aren't changed. Many times we use surrogate keys like CustomerID. One could use a really-unique key like in the case of VIN (vehicle identification number). Such naturally unique keys are called natural keys.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization doesn't require you to introduce surrogate keys.  It's not about eliminating duplicate values either.  The purpose of normalization is to avoid recording the same fact more than once, since multiple instances of the same fact could be updated inconsistently and cause anomalies.

The 1st normal form is slightly different from the rest, since its purpose is to ensure that your data is in a regular arrangement of scalar values so that normalization can be applied systematically.  For the 1st normal form, you need to ensure that every field of every row contains a single value.  "Obj1,Obj2" looks like multiple values, so you might want to start there.  Then, write out your functional dependencies before proceeding to the higher normal forms.